# Does food absorb a chametz ta'am if there is no heat (or equivalent) involved?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, passover, chametz-leaven

This is a case where I am fairly certain that I know the practical halacha, but don't understand the issues underlying the practice.

Let's say you chop up some apples and nuts before Pesach on a chametz cuttingboard (that hasn't been used for several days prior), with a chametz knife (same), and store it in a new, never-used glass jar in your fridge.  Can the apples and nuts be used on Pesach, for example as charoset?

My (limited) understanding is that the *ta'am* of a food is only transmitted from a vessel or utensil into the food item if heat is applied, or if the food has an intrinsic "sharpness" (like onions or radishes).  And in any case the *ta'am* of the chametz would be stale at the time the food is prepared.  Furthermore, we know that before Pesach chametz can be *batel*.  So it would seem that there is really no reason one could not use such food on Pesach.  And yet, I am sure that everyone would agree it may not be done.  What am I overlooking?

A follow-up question:  What if instead of charoset, you are making home-made sauerkraut?  Again there is no heat, and no intrinsic sharpness in the cabbage.  The only difference here is that the chopped cabbage is pounded to soften it and bring out the brine, before being allowed to ferment.  Does either the act of pounding, or the natural fermentation process, behave analogously to heat insofar as the transmission of *ta'am* is concerned?

Comment: https://oukosher.org/blog/kosher-professionals/lo-basi-ella-lorer-kavush/#fn2239895450cf4c6bc581b

Comment: @Loewian I am not sure what part of the linked page is relevant for my question...  could you elaborate?

Comment: How is this different from eating apples cut up with a knife previously used to cut pig?

Comment: @DoubleAA perhaps it’s exactly the same. What exactly is the reason that’s prohibited? I know it *is*, but why?

Comment: I believe I've heard some consider apples "sharp" for kashruth purposes (because of their tanginess). As always, cylor.

Answer (score 1):

You write

> So it would seem that there is really no reason one could not use such
> food on Pesach. And yet, I am sure that everyone would agree it may
> not be done. What am I overlooking?

The first part of your statement was correct. You can actually use this food on Pesach if the cutting board and knives were clean and you are sure no *hametz* was around and might have mixed in.

More than that

> if before Pesach food was cooked (or remained soaking for 24 hours) in
> a *hametz* utensil that was not a *ben yomo* [wasn't used for 24
> hours], the food may even be eaten on Pesach, see [Mishna Brura
> 447:39](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.447.5?lang=bi&with=Mishnah%20Berurah&lang2=en) (quoted from footnote 4 to Artscroll's Kitzur Shulchan
> Aruch 112:2).

The reason is that, as you write, taste doesn't transfer if the utensils are cold and clean. In addition, *hametz* that might be absorbed in the dishes is annulled in sixty times its volume before Pesach (but **not** during Pesach).

Regarding the sauerkraut, there is indeed a rule of *[kavush k'mevushal](https://ph.yhb.org.il/en/04-10-14/)* (soaking is like cooking) but if the cabbage is clear of *hamets* and with the rule above, it can still be eaten during Pesach.

Now whether or not you can rely on this ruling in practice, either before the fact or after the fact, depends on what your rabbi will tell you. In modern days, when getting Pesach dishes is so easy and cheap, there is less need to rely on leniencies and "risky practices".

PS. As always things get complicated when cutting onions or other *davar charif* so the above might not apply directly in this case.